# C++ Alternativa a getch()?

Tags: c++

Conocen alguna alternativa a la funcion `getch()`? porque es de la libreria Conio (que no es estandar) y quisiera saber si hay alguna alternativa estandar para C++.

Tengo este codigo:

```
 do
 {
      tecla = getch();
 } while (tecla != TECLA_ARRIBA && tecla != TECLA_ABAJO && tecla != ENTER);
```

No deseo una pausa, deseo capturar datos como el codigo ejemplo.

Nota: o caso contrario, algun codigo que emule la funcion?

Comment: Hay una respuesta en SO en inglés, pero se entiende: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1378312/5587982

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es leer las entradas directas de las teclas, sin pasar por el *buffer* de entrada `std::cin`.

En ese caso, la respuesta es simple: **no** hay una forma estándar, puesto que depende del Sistema Operativo que uses.

Si estás en la *emulación de consola* de Windows, ya sabes lo que usar: `conio.h`

Si usas una aplicación gráfica, no tienes mas opción que recurrir al sistema de eventos que te proporcione el sistema operativo, o a la librería de *mas alto nivel* que uses.

El modo mas *portable* sería usando la librería *ncurses*. Si bien es nativa de sistemas *nix, puede ser usada en los emuladores de terminal de Windows. En el capítulo 11 de `NCURSES Programming HOWTO`, [`Interfacing with the keyboard`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/keys.html), tienes un ejemplo completo.

Como última opción, si estás en Linux, puedes establecer el teclado en modo *raw*, accediendo directamente a los eventos que genera. Tienes un ejemplo completo en [`Grab Raw Keyboard Input`](http://www.thelinuxdaily.com/2010/05/grab-raw-keyboard-input-from-event-device-node-devinputevent/).

Comment: supongo que no queda opcion, una lastima que no se halla integrando una funcion asi en el estandar, gracias Trauma

Comment: Como indica eferion, *entrada estándar* es un termino *abstracto*. Es imposible concretar algo así y que sea común a todos los sistemas. Piensa en otras cosas, que no sean PC: equipos integrados, quioscos, maquinaria industrial, ... C++ es *portable*, se puede usar en muchos tipos de máquinas.

Answer (score 3):

No puedes hacer lo que pretendes. Al menos no tirando del estándar de C++.

C++ no entiende ni de teclados ni de consolas sino de entrada estándar y de salida estándar. Este cambio de concepto, aunque pueda parecer trivial tiene sus implicaciones:

- En el caso del teclado, que el estándar no sepa que está tratando con un teclado implica que no va a ser capaz de reconocer las teclas especiales ya que las mismas no se almacenan en el buffer de entrada. La entrada estándar podría ser perfectamente un fichero y en el mismo no pueden encontrarse las teclas de *flecha arriba* o *flecha abajo* (por poner un ejemplo) y en consecuencia el estándar no provee ninguna característica especial para capturar estas pulsaciones.
- En el caso de la consola, la salida estándar no tiene por qué ser necesariamente una consola sino que también puede ser un fichero o incluso podría ser una impresora. Es facil entender entonces que no tiene sentido hablar de filas y columnas sino de una salida en serie. Es por este motivo que la librería estándar de C++ no disponde de ninguna funcionalidad que te permita colocar el cursor en una posición determinada de la consola.

La única opción que te queda es tirar de librerías dependientes del SO para realizar esta tarea: [`conio.h`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) (Windows), [`ncurses`](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/) (Linux), [`pdcurses`](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) (Windows),
etc.

Comment: gracias Eferion, muy completa tu explicacion, con razon C++ no atiende el entorno visual

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar `cin.get( );` de la libreria `iostream` y pone a su disposición los objetos `cin, cout`.

ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hola mundo";    
    std::cin.get();    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin.get()` no te va a servir para capturar la pulsación de las flechas del teclado...